# Git unable to access in connection to the DNS

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using Atlassian for my Git repository. I'm currently facing a problem right now that when I am trying to push this error shows up

```
fatal: unable to access `https://po_c_user@xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx:` OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
```

Could someone help me out? I already checked :

`Tools->Git->Disable SSL certificate validation (note: potentially insecure)`

But still, the error occurs. I've searched a  lot but can't find any solid one. Hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by checking if my git server is running. Sorry for the troubles

`unabled to access  because  git server was shutdowned`